# SMNP module for Python

Tags: linux, python, windows-xp, snmp

The most popular seems to be [SNMP library for Python](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pysnmp/).

Alas, it gives errors when trying to install on Windows, so I am looking for an alternative.

Must support SNMP 3 (but we don't need the crypto (I *know*, why not just use v2? Because ... customer)).

Must have server functionality, agent a bonus.

Must be able to install and run on Windows (with no admin rights) and Linux.

Comment: Have you tried `pip install -U pysnmp` - it installs absolutely fine on my Windows 10-64 under python 2.7.11 (32 bit) - otherwise if you are still having problems why not raise a bug report on the tracker, https://sourceforge.net/p/pysnmp/bugs/, detailing what goes wrong and what your set-up is the developer(s) are very responsive.

Comment: Alas, my company considers Windows XP, 32-bit, with no administrative rights  (for security porpoises) to be sufficient

Comment: Have you pointed out to them that that is itself insecure as XP is no longer receiving security updates. You might wish to update your question to include that you need it to run on XP rather than just Windows or windows back to XP.

Comment: We have pointed out to the that our company critical project with an incredibly tight dealine requires tools which will only run on Windows 7 & higher. IT are located in a city far aaway and rules are rules, and ... jobsworth

Comment: Then I would suggest implementing for Linux & Windows 7+ and telling IT/management that they will have to wait/pay for legacy, unsupported, system.

Comment: These guys cannot be moved. There is a plan for a test pilot of Windows 7 at another site "later this year".  We can apply after that. They will brook no further discussion.

Comment: @SteveBarnes  `no such option: -U` on that ipi command :-(

Comment: that was `pip install -U pysnmp` with a capital __U__ which has been available for pip for a long time, alternative is `pip install --upgrade pysnmp`

Comment: `-U` didn't work for me on 2.7. I tried `--upgrade`, but have corporate firewall problems. I will update the question to ask for ZIP files only, no installers. Thanks for your help, Steve

Comment: You can download the egg  from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysnmp/4.3.0 and then install with pip

Comment: Sorry to soun ddumb, but what doi I do with an EGG? Can I pip from that?  if so, feel free to post that as an asnwer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest is, assuming no firewall problems, use:

```
pip install -U pysnmp
```

If you are behind a firewall that will not let you do that then can go to the [pysnmp pypi page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysnmp) and download the egg file for pysnmp to match your python version, e.g. if you are using python 2.7.x you can download `pysnmp-4.3.0-py2.7.egg` *4.3.0 being the current version at the time of writing.* This can then be installed with `easy_install` e.g.:

```
easy_install pysnmp-4.3.0-py2.7.egg
```

You may find that there are some unmet dependencies that you need to follow a similar process for.